# What is the difference between とある and ある?

Tags: nuances

As far as I'm aware, とある means 'some':

> とある会社の従業員
>   An employee of some company

And just ある can be used to mean the same thing.

Does that give a different level of formality? A more 'direct' or pointed way to referring to the following noun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same thing. However, 「ある」 is more common nowadays, especially among the younger generation.

Sources:

- [Chiebukuro](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1296602837)
- [lang-8](http://lang-8.com/554045/journals/287427577267505715082110860385120298845)

Comment: Thanks for the sources. To confirm: とある apparently isn't used at all in daily speech right now? One answer states that they find it a pompous thing to say, though I don't think I see the same sentiment in other answers. Is that an actual thing or just that person's opinion? (Or were they referring to とある making the *noun* seem more important?)